# How to surround a Drupal view with some tags?

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-views

Let's say I have a view that returns some items. I want to display the items in an unordered list, so I rewrite the field output with `<li>[field]</li>`. Now I only have to surround the view with `<ul>`and `</ul>` tags.

However, when I add those tags as "full HTML" to the view's header and footer areas, they are being surrounded by a `div` like so:

```
<div class="view-header">
    <ul>
</div>
```

which kinda defeats the purpose, as the UL tag is ignored by some Browsers / jQuery versions.

How can I get rid of the `div`s around the `<ul>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your concrete need, you can save yourself the trouble of overriding templates and **just configure the view directly** to use the style 'HTML List', with list type 'Unordered list'. (On the views configuration page, under 'Basic settings').

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to override `views-view.tpl.php` so that instead of producing `div`s it only produces `ul`s. Alright. Now I only have to find a template for `views-view-fields.tpl.php`to override that as well.